# Why addEventListener works unexpected on element remove?

Tags: javascript, dom

```js
$lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

for (let i = 0; i < $lis.length; i++) {
  $li = $lis[i];
  $span = $li.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
  $button = $li.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

  $button.addEventListener('click', $li.remove);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>1</span>
    <button>x</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

On the last line I'm using `Element.remove()` method, but instead of deleting the `<li>` it deletes `<button>`.

Explain to me, please, why. I feel that there is something with `this` happening, but I want to understand this completely not just **feel**.

*P.S. I also understand that I can solve this by wrapping the `$li.remove` in an anonymous function, but the point of my question is to understand described behaviour not just to solve the problem. Thanks.*

Comment: relevant documentation [EventTarget.addEventListener()
: The value of "this" within the handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_value_of_this_within_the_handler)

Answer (score 2):

In this line `$button.addEventListener('click', $li.remove);` you are passing the `$li`'s `remove` method as your click handler. The nature of click handlers (and other user-event handlers) is to rebind `this` in the handler function to the element you attach the listener to, so what really happens is

```
$li.remove.call($button)
```

You can fix it using `bind`:

```
$button.addEventListener('click', $li.remove.bind($li))
```

Sidenote:

Replace the live `HTMLCollection` `document.getElementsByTagName('li')` with a static `NodeList` by using `document.querySelectorAll('li')`.

Removing an element from the DOM will also immediately remove it from any `HTMLCollection` it is part of, messing up your indexes.

Comment: I understand it's not damaging in this case due to the static references like `$li = $lis[i]`, but it can easily become a footgun if someone changes the code.

Comment: That's all I was trying to point out. That is wasn't at issue here, but worth understanding the difference.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the button because the new context or `this` that `Element.remove()` is called with. An anyonmous function, or more accurately, an arrow function, uses the lexical scope that it's declared in as the context, that's why it works.

So `button.addEventListener('click', elementX.remove)` actually takes the prototype function `remove` and calls it with the button as the context or in other words, it `bind`s it to the button.

A way to demonstrate binding can work, is by binding `remove` to the element, then adding it as the event handler `$li.remove.bind($li)` this way, regardless of the implicit context, we've explicitly set it to `$li`.

```js
$lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

for (let i = 0; i < $lis.length; i++) {
    $li = $lis[i];
    $span = $li.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
    $button = $li.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
    let remove = $li.remove.bind($li)

    $button.addEventListener('click', remove);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>1</span>
    <button>x</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```